# VBA String applied as filtered rows in Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, m

Is there a way to Define a string based on a cell value for a VBA recorded Power Query? I have tried setting the string as

```
    Dim Test As String
    TestFilter = """" & "Filter" & """"
```

But the #Filtered Rows is not recognizing the input I.e

```
    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows = ([Filter1] = TestFilter)
```

This is not recognizing the string in VBA. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the VBA to assign the variable contents to a named range

Use that range name in place of **NamedRangeName** below

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows = ([Filter1] = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NamedRangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```